# kubernetes do not schedule anything unless specified

Tags: kubernetes

kubernetes do not schedule anything to node unless specified

I am adding a node to the cluster. But i don't want pods to scheduled to it. I only want the services which are specified to run on this to be scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a taint to the node and add toleration for the taint in pod spec for pods which you want to be scheduled in that node.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/